# Simple SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

I'm training my SQLInjection knowledge on a training tool made by my university.
In a certain lvl there is this simple product viewer which gets a row based on a id.
So the query should me something like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?`
There is a simple security layer which filters some chars (and char combinations) like OR and such.

The following input gets me four results instead of one:
`1 | 1 is not null`

**GOAL:** get the users pass

*Additional info:*
There is a user table with a password column.
The wanted user has the 'name' 'Piet'

How could I get my injection to work such that it will return the password somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps inject a `union`?  You will need to know what columns are returned by the base query.  Say you determine that the original query is essentially returning:

```
SELECT id, productName, productDescription, createdDate FROM Products where ID = 1
```

You can craft a `UNION` query that matches the same column structure but queries another table.  Then if you pass in the following instead of `1`:
`1 UNION SELECT null, userName, userPassword, null FROM users`

It will create the following query:

```
SELECT id, productName, productDescription, createdDate 
FROM Products 
where ID = 1 
UNION 
SELECT null, userName, userPassword, null 
FROM users
```

Which basically appends another query that hits the user table and returns username/password.

Ideally this would give you the password because the password would be salted/hashed, but if the exercise is asking you to get the password it probably isn't.  Just keep in mind that in a real world scenario you would salt/hash your passwords to protect against your database being compromised.

Comment: THNKS!, worked, the following query got me the answer: 1 UNION SELECT null, name, password, null FROM users

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on what characters are actually filtered.

My first try would be an injection using:

### UNION SELECT

You can test it quickly with: id=**1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM products**.

If It gets you all the products instead of only one, it works. You then have to guess the number of columns for products and their type (there are a lot of ways for that, google's your friend).

If products is a 4-column table with data types (varchar, varchar, int, int):

```
id=1 UNION ALL SELECT (name,password,0,0) FROM products
```

Will get you the name:password combination.

There might be a lot of other ways to get what you want, https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/ might help you.

Comment: Hi MadWard, Thnx for the fast response. All chars are indeed allows. I only get the following response:
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lvl1.php on line 38

Comment: What can you write, and what can you not ? Does the first test query I wrote get through ?

Comment: See response on Abe ;) Thnks for helping out!